# Binary search tree recursive insert method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, haskell, data-structures, functional-programming

My question is about how to simplify the recursive version of `insert` into binary search tree to the bare minimum. Suppose that I want to create a BST out of array of values.

This is how I would do it in JavaScript (these are methods of BST class).

```
_insert(target, key) {
  if (target.key > key) {
    if (!target.left) {
      target.left = new Node(key);
    } else {
      this._insert(target.left, key);
    }
  } else {
    if (!target.right) {
      target.right = new Node(key);
    } else {
      this._insert(target.right, key);
    }
  }
}

insert(key) {
  if (!this.root) {
    this.root = new Node(key);
  } else {
    this._insert(this.root, key);
  }
}

fill(keys) { keys.forEach(k => this.insert(k)); }
```

On the other hand, in Haskell I would do something like this:

```
singleton :: a -> Tree a
singleton x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree

insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x EmptyTree = singleton x
insert x t@(Node a left right)
  | x == a = t
  | x < a = Node a (insert x left) right
  | x > a = Node a left (insert x right)

fill :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Tree a
fill [] = EmptyTree
fill xs = foldr insert EmptyTree $ reverse xs
```

The Haskell version is obviously much more concise and easier to read than the JavaScript version.

My question is, can I somehow simplify the JavaScript version to make it more “Haskell-like” (I know that I could rewrite those methods into functions without the need of a BST class but the code would be very similar to the this one)? That JavaScript code is the best I came up with.

Comment: Maybe more suited for codereview?

Comment: If you were using immutable data structures in JavaScript, you could write more or less the same thing as the Haskell code, just with different syntax. For example, `var insert = (x, t) => t.empty ? singleton(x) : x == a ? t : x < a ? node(a, insert(x, t.left), t.right) : node(a, t.left, insert(x, t.right));`. Is that what you mean by “the code would be very similar to this one”?

Comment: @JonPurdy Thanks, I will try that.